# How to solve "Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<String>"?

Tags: apex, batch, casting, iterable

I'm working on a library that handles the exposes an iterable batch dynamically. Relevant code:

```
public abstract class BatchIterable implements Database.Batchable<Object> {
    protected abstract Iterable<Object> start();

    protected abstract void execute(List<Object> scope);

    protected override abstract Boolean finish();

    public Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return this.start();
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Object> scope) {
        this.execute(scope);
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

And the implementation is as follows:

```
public class BatchIterableImplementation extends BatchIterable {
    private String testRecordName;

    public BatchIterableImplementation(String testRecordName) {
        this.testRecordName = testRecordName;
    }

    protected override Iterable<Object> start() {
        return new List<Object>{ this.testRecordName };
    }

    protected override void execute(List<Object> scope) {
        String testRecordName = ((List<String>) scope)[0];
        TestUtility.insertTestRecord(testRecordName);
    }

    protected override Boolean finish() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run `Database.executeBatch(new BatchIterableImplementation('Test Record Name'), 200);`, I get the following error: `Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<String>`

The only workaround I've found is to pass the Type to the base class, serialize List, and then deserialize to the specific type (like so):

```
public abstract class BatchIterable implements Database.Batchable<Object> {
    private Type listType;

    public BatchIterable(Type listType) {
        this.listType = listType;
    }

    ...
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Object> scope) {
        List<Object> castedList = (List<Object>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(scope), this.listType);
        this.execute(castedList);
    }

    ...
}
```

And then updating the extending class to pass the type to the base class' constructor:

```
public class BatchIterableImplementation extends BatchIterable {
    ...

    public BatchIterableImplementation(String testRecordName) {
        super(List<String>.class);
        this.testRecordName = testRecordName;
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there any way I can do casting without requiring the extending class to pass the type of the iterable to the base class?

And I have reviewed other answers on this forum but they're primarily focused on casting lists to maps which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    return new List<Object>{ this.testRecordName };
```

Should be:

```
    return (Iterable<Object>)new List<String>{ this.testRecordName };
```

As long as we have a proper iterable type, things will work as you expect.

Here's a quick demo.

```
public Iterable<Object> start() {
    return (Iterable<Object>)new String[] { 'Hello', 'World' };
}
Iterator<String> it = (Iterator<String>)start().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    system.debug(it.next());
}
```

This code is meant to be run in Execute Anonymous. You'll see I cast it upwards towards `Iterable<Object>` for the return type, then I can cast it back downwards for the appropriate data type later.

You can also do conversion directly back into the list type:

```
public Iterable<Object> start() {
    return (Iterable<Object>)new String[] { 'Hello', 'World' };
}
String[] values = (String[])start();
for(String value: values) {
    System.debug(value);
}
```

You just need to make sure that `start`'s actual return value matches the expected data type in the execute `method`.

Here's your fixed implementation:

```
public class BatchIterableImplementation extends BatchIterable {
    private String testRecordName;

    public BatchIterableImplementation(String testRecordName) {
        this.testRecordName = testRecordName;
    }

    protected override Iterable<Object> start() {
        return (Iterable<Object>)new List<String>{ this.testRecordName };
    }

    protected override void execute(List<Object> scope) {
        String testRecordName = ((List<String>) scope)[0];
        TestUtility.insertTestRecord(testRecordName);
    }

    protected override Boolean finish() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox worked like a charm :)